# ERROR/Input Dispatcher: Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed (Android)

Tags: android

I'm making an Android app for my final project and everything was fine and working until I added one more activity. Then, when I try to login the Sign in button does not start the main activity and does not crash either, basically nothing happens. After stopping my app, I get this:

```
W/InputDispatcher: channel 'ca84fab checkapp.com.br.checkapp/checkapp.com.br.activities.InicioActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher: channel 'ca84fab checkapp.com.br.checkapp/checkapp.com.br.activities.InicioActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'ca84fab checkapp.com.br.checkapp/checkapp.com.br.activities.InicioActivity (server)'
```

How can I fix that? I tried to delete the new activity but it does not help, but it happened after I added it.

Thanks!